# carga de web en un div mediante load, como volver atras

Tags: div

Muy buenas, estoy intentando gestionar el boton de atras, el problema es que yo tengo un solo div donde voy cargando los enlaces mediante load.

$('#ejemplo').load(menu); Donde menu es una cadena donde paso las variables que necesito por get.

El problema es que cuando llamo a una pagina tengo que pasarle todas las variables necesirias para volver atras y poder cargar la pagina de atras, esto lo veo muy engoroso, no se si hay otra forma de hacerlo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Lorenzo. Esta pregunta es muy amplia/basada en opiniones... creo que lo mejor seria que investigaras (o preguntaras por el chat alguna manera ) y si en el desarrollo de la misma tienes errores o preguntas , explicar eso concretamente aqui siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Muy bien. Gracias

Comment: @LorenzoMartín ¿resolviste el problema?

Comment: Muy buenas, no encontré solución para eso,  cambie totalmente la forma de programar la web, solo uso un div en en ese div voy cargandolo todo.